# Call application after apply patch (MSP)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, deployment, installation

I use the tutorial from the following to create MSP file.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/dotnetpatching.aspx?fid=209224&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&select=2567089

However, I want to call my application after apply MSP. Please help me. I am using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate or you can suggest me any tools to make this work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a custom action which has this condition:

```
PATCH
```

The [PATCH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370576%28VS.85%29.aspx) property is automatically set by Windows Installer only during a patch installation.